# Metadata locking - Table creation with FK constraint in Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

While creating table FK constraint, facing meta data locking issue.
First create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE parent_meta_lock_test (SEID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
VALUE1 VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Client 1;

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * from parent_meta_lock_test limit 1;
Empty set (0.02 sec)
```

Client 2:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE child_meta_lock_test ( ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL, PARENT_ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES parent_meta_lock_test (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here Client 2 is waiting for metadata lock for parent_meta_lock_test

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks;
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA      | OBJECT_NAME           | COLUMN_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE            | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| TABLE       | test               | parent_meta_lock_test | NULL        |       105553151881808 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6140 |              48 |             11 |
| SCHEMA      | test               | NULL                  | NULL        |       105553151881488 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | dd_schema.cc:108  |              48 |             11 |
| GLOBAL      | NULL               | NULL                  | NULL        |       105553151880848 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5475  |              49 |              7 |
| BACKUP LOCK | NULL               | NULL                  | NULL        |       105553151880768 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5482  |              49 |              7 |
| SCHEMA      | test               | NULL                  | NULL        |       105553151880208 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_base.cc:5462  |              49 |              7 |
| TABLE       | test               | child_meta_lock_test  | NULL        |       105553151880448 | SHARED              | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6140 |              49 |              7 |
| SCHEMA      | test               | NULL                  | NULL        |       105553151880528 | INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE | STATEMENT     | GRANTED     | sql_table.cc:9920 |              49 |              7 |
| TABLE       | test               | parent_meta_lock_test | NULL        |       105553151881888 | EXCLUSIVE           | STATEMENT     | PENDING     | sql_table.cc:9912 |              49 |              7 |
| TABLE       | performance_schema | metadata_locks        | NULL        |       105553151818512 | SHARED_READ         | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:6140 |              50 |             10 |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

After this all upcoming clients which query parent_meta_lock_test are also waiting for metadata lock.

Same issue was not occurring Mysql 5.7.30. when i migrate to Mysql 8 faced this issue.